# Converting string to int/float in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting a value from a div :

```
<div id="test">100</div>
```

And what I want to do is to get the value with jQuery, raise with 50% and show the value.

```
$number= $('#test').text() //getting the value, without parseInt or parseFloat?
$newNumber = $number * 0,5 //show the result of this
```

I often end up with NaN, so I'd like to have a guidance on that. Thank you.

Comment: Use [**parseFloat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat): `var $number = parseFloat($('#test').text(), 10)`

Comment: @arnaud576875 `*` will automatically parse it to number

Comment: @A.Wolff just because you can doesn't mean you should

Comment: @arnaud576875 Itsn't at all, but using an useless parameter is, at the opposite, ugly, parseFloat accepting only one parameter ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff oops, old [parseInt() habits](http://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix)

Comment: $number = parseFloat($('#test').text,10) returns NaN

That's weird.

Comment: @user2142447 At least, copy exact code, `text()` is a method: `$number = parseFloat($('#test').text());` and forget the second parameter, there isn't any here for parseFloat() method. And anyway, that's not relevant to your issue here, `0,5` isn't a number

Comment: Sorry, I did exactly that, just misspelled it here.
But the problem stays - still returns NaN. What can be the issue, as I checked the code more than once.

Comment: As you can see, works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/E38tR/

Comment: Thank you! It is really weird, and still gives me back that NaN.
What if the number is 123,456 inside the div?

Comment: Well again, `123,456` isn't a valid number. That's said you could just replace any comma with a dot in string. You have to start to take some initiative on your side... `var $number = $('#test').text().replace(',','.');`  Or use `parseFloat()`. It looks like you are just copying/pasting code without firstly trying to understand it.

Comment: Thank you again. I really want to say that worked, but it gives me this NaN in the console. I will try to solve it on a separate file and see where the problem is.

Comment: @Beginner You are welcome, glad you have accepted other answer than mine, which anyway doesn't fix your issue when it comes to invalid number... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have following markups:

```
<div id="test">100</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

what you are looking for can be achieved as following (without using parseInt() or parseFloat() functions)

```
var number = $('#test').text();
var result = Number(number) + (number * 0.5);
$('#result').html(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your code, just fix it with:

```
$number * 0.5
```

Using dot, not comma.